# Recover Edge (Windows) saved passwords

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I lost a hard drive to a firmware bug, but managed to recover the data from it. I've obtained the passwords from my Firefox profile back, but Edge seems to store it in a different place.

They're not synced to my account, and the haven't appeared there.

From googling, it would seem that they're stored in my Credentials Manager.

Is it possible to access the credentials somehow?

Comment: Did you encrypt the passwords? Have you looked in the Edge user profile?

Comment: @Ramhound I've copied the User Data folder and recovered all my tabs and history; passwords weren't included. They weren't encrypted AFAIK (in any case I still have access to the drive if the key is stored with it).

Comment: Have you restored the saved files to your profile folder in Edge, as well as folder `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default` ?

Comment: @harrymc yes, passwords aren't saved there.

Comment: If you have restored the above two locations and the passwords aren't there, then they are lost. This is why one should use a third-party password manager such as LastPass.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I found a free program that decodes the vault, but it does not cointain all passwords

Comment: @Tordek - It should have. Edge is a Chromium browser. Key is not stored, if not already exported, and you were using encryption the key is essentially lost.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - The article you linked to isn’t applicable to any Chromium version of Edge

Comment: @Ramhound could there be another file or registry setting missing? I have everything on the drive available to access, so the key must exist somewhere.

Comment: @Tordek - I asked if you encrypted the password(s) you stored with Edge. I don’t exactly recall what you said, but the password, was encrypted with the users password.  If there isn’t a file called “Login Data” which is a SQLite database contained within “%localappdata%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default” on the original profile the passwords are gone forever and there’s nothing that can be done. Note it appears after additional reading the passwords are encrypted regardless if a password was used to protect them. The information I read says, AES encryption, accessible only to the logged in user

Comment: There is a 580KB file called Login Data, yes; I don't know how the encryption works in Edge, I don't remember activating it manually but it did ask me for my user account password to access it (but I could use them on autocomplete without a master password).

Comment: It would seem the last resort is to image the whole drive and try to boot from the old windows installation.